# Registering Middleware that needs services

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing a middleware that requires a handful of scoped dependencies to be registered. Is there a way to register this middleware without having to put code in both the `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods of `Startup.cs` ?

Comment: It is not possible .coz startup.cs class is just like an entry point.

Answer (score 0):

No. Services and Middlewares are not the same. And there is no way to inject some service before the DI container knows about it. In other words, we need to register these services before we inject them into middleware.

You could create a by-convention middleware instead:

```
public class ConventionalMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ConventionalMiddleware(RequestDelegate next){
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, Service1 s1, Service2 s2, ...)
    {

        // ...
    }
}
```

and `UseMiddleware<ConventionalMiddleware>()` within `Configure()` will lift the weight.

Comment: I'm writing a Plugin that I want to distribute as a NuGet. I would like to make it easy to use and easy to register. In your example above, assume that both ConventionalMiddleware and Service1, Service2 come from the NuGet. I'm asking if I can register both the Middleware and Services in one method.

Comment: No. Services and Middlewares are not the same. And there's no way to  inject some service before the  DI container knows it. In other words, we need register these services before we inject them in middlewares. If you could do that, why the ASP.NET Core Team makes us  do `services.AddMvc()` and do `app.UseMvc()`  again?